# Kentico 12 Azure Search

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

I'm trying to implement Azure Search on Kentico 12. Following the article below.

https://docs.kentico.com/k12/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/using-azure-search/integrating-azure-search-into-pages

However, I have multiple indexes defined on the smart search not just a single index code name that I can hard code and also cannot aford to hard code index fields. Is there any tutorial out there that I can follow?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you're referring to building an Azure Search web part, is this correct.  If so, make a property in your web part which allows you to select the code name from a list in the database.  Secondly, regarding field names, you should be using generic field names like `DocumentName`, `NodeAliaspath`, etc. Although if you have very specific search results that need to be displayed, simply put in a switch statement to get the field names based on a class name.